# How do I select a particular edit controller from Microsoft Office dialog box using Pywinauto and Python

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto, office-automation

I am trying to create a Python script that will automatically fill the Journal Article details in "Create Source" dialog box of Microsoft Word with the provided data.

Basically, I want to fill the Input boxes programatically with variables containing the appropriate data for "Author", "Title" "Journal Name", "Year" etc.

[image: I want to fill these marked boxes programatically with variables]

I am trying to select these boxes by using Pywinauto.  I have successfully connected Microsoft Word and Selected the "Create Source" dialg box using the following code:

> app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Document1 - Word')
>
> createSource = app.Document1Word.window(title='Create Source').print_control_identifiers()

The snippet from the ***Control Identifiers*** from the above code"

> ```
>    | Edit - ''    (L1278, T511, R1669, B525)
>    | ['EditorEdit', 'Edit10', 'EditorEdit0', 'EditorEdit1']
>    | child_window(auto_id="86", control_type="Edit")
>    | 
>    | Edit - ''    (L1278, T534, R1753, B548)
>    | ['PublisherEdit', 'Edit11', 'PublisherEdit0', 'PublisherEdit1']
>    | child_window(auto_id="93", control_type="Edit")
>    | 
>    | Edit - ''    (L1228, T563, R1763, B574)
>    | ['VolumeEdit', 'Edit12', 'VolumeEdit0', 'VolumeEdit1']
>    | child_window(auto_id="96", control_type="Edit")
> ```

Now lets say, if I target the "publisher" using *`child_window(auto_id="93", control_type="Edit")`*. It works fine for the first time. But the problem is that these `auto_id`s change each time the program, or even the dialog box, restarts. For example, now the `auto_id="93"` for the "Publisher" editbox (Input Box), next time it may be, say, 57 or anything arbitratory. This breaks the whole script.

What I am doing:

> ```
> app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Document1 - Word')
> createSource = app.Document1Word.window(title='Create Source')
> EditPublisherName = createSource.child_window(auto_id="93", control_type="Edit").wrapper_object()
> EditPublisherName.set_edit_text("XYZ Publishers")
> ```

Again, for the first time above code, works perfectly fine. It fills the "Publisher" edit box with "XYZ Publisher" string. However this script would fail to work if I restart the dialog box. And when I run the `.print_control_identifiers()` after restarting the program or dialog box, all the **auto_ids** would have been changed.
Is there a better way to target these edit boxes?

[image: Code fills the publisher edit box]

Comment: AutoID changing is very fishy! Is Alias names are also changing ?

Comment: @Sreevasthsabr How to target Alias names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, the alias Name doesn't change from one run to another runs. If so we can do something like this.

```
set_text=app.DialogName["PublisherEdit"].type_keys("XYZ Publishers")
```

Need to try something like this